# Multiple examination of a result (probability)

Tags: probability

A performs a task and submits the result to B and C for examination.
B confirms the result.
C thinks the result is wrong.

The reliability of A is 0.7, for B is 0.8 and that of C is 0.9.
(reliablity = probability that the result/statement is correct).

What is the probability that A performed the task correctly?

---

I first tried to solve a simpler case where both B and C confirm the result.
The probability that the result is correct is then given by:
1 - (1-0.7)*(1-0.8)*(1-0.9) = 0.994

Now, as for the original question, I think it's wrong to calculate:
1 - (1-0.7)*(1-0.8)*0.9 = 0.946

...because if C had a reliability of 1, the result must equal 0, which is not the case...

Comment: This is not a "do my homework for free" service. Please show what you've tried!

Comment: It's not my homework. The question is related to reputation of workers in crowdworking environments. 

I think the problem has something to do with conditional probabilites (theorem of Bayes?)

Comment: You still need to show your effort before asking others to do it for you.

Comment: Your comment has been deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the event A performed the task correctly, and let $T$ be the event B says she did and C says she did not. We want the conditional probability $\Pr(S|T)$.  By definition this is equal to $\Pr(S\cap T)/\Pr(T)$.

The calculation of $\Pr(S\cap T)$ is easy. Assuming independence (unlikely, but we are implicitly expected to assume it), we find that it is $(0.7)(0.8)(0.1)$.

The event $T$ can happen in $2$ ways: either (i) A was right, B was right, and C was wrong, or (ii) A was wrong, B was wrong, and C was right. We have already calculated the probability of (i). The probability of (ii) is $(0.3)(0.2)(0.9)$. So our conditional probability is $\frac{(0.7)(0.8)(0.1)}{(0.7)(0.8)(0.1)+(0.3)(0.2)(0.9)}.$

**Remark:** The "simpler" case mentioned in the OP is not done correctly. Again, a conditional probability is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the good explanation!

Comment: You   are welcome. Somehow the "formula" I used disappeared. It has been reinserted.

Comment: Thanks for reinserting. I see that the event T can happen in two ways. However, I don't really understand why independence between S and T is unlikely.

Comment: We multiplied to compute probabilities. But for example it is unlikely that the events B is right and C is wrong are independent. Maybe C is sharper than B, and whenever B is right,  C is also right.  Then A right, B right, C wrong never happens.